# Rust println! result is different that print! when using time::sleep

Tags: string, rust

Ok, so I haven't worked with Rust for that long so sorry if this is dumb. But I'm trying to make a print function that takes in a string and then prints the string character by character on the same line and has a pause between each character. Here's the function:

```
fn talk(input: String){
    let inputVec: Vec<char> = input.chars().collect();
    
    let mut i = 0;
    loop{
        thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(100));
        if i >= inputVec.len() {
            break;
        }
        print!("{}", inputVec[i]);
        i = i + 1;
    }
}
```

When I do this code with the print! macro, it doesn't work and just waits 100 milliseconds before printing the string as one print! call. But if I use println! then it works perfectly minus the new line for every character. Can someone help me with this or at least tell me why it doesn't work?

Comment: Have you tried flushing stdout after each print?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the comments of Vivick and drewtato, you need use flush of Write io's module Trait.

```rust
use std::{thread, time};
use std::io::{self, Write};

fn main() {
    talk("Hello, world!\n".to_string());
}

fn talk (input: String) {
    let chars = Vec::<u8>::from(input);
    let mut i = 0;
    while i < chars.len() {
        print!("{}", chars[i] as char);
        io::stdout().flush().unwrap();
        thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(100));
        i+=1;
    }
}
```

This works for me!

But, the most simple way to do this is use `eprint!` macro, like this:

```rust
use std::{thread, time};

fn main() {
    talk("Hello, world!\n".to_string());
}

fn talk (input: String) {
    let chars = Vec::<u8>::from(input);
    let mut i = 0;
    while i < chars.len() {
        eprint!("{}", chars[i] as char);
        thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(100));
        i+=1;
    }
}
```

and the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.eprint.html) says:

> Use `eprint!` only for error and progress messages. Use `print!` instead for the primary output of your program.